# Adding the degree symbol at the end of each vector element in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of numerical values, say:

```
angles <- c(10.2, 20.3, 14.3, 18.4)
```

And I want to append the degree symbol at the end of each element, in order to obtain:

```
labels <- c("10.2°", "20.3°", "14.3°", "18.4°")
```

I tried with bquote() function without success:

```
labels <- bquote(paste(.(angles) * degree))
```

Comment: `paste0(angles,"°")`?

Comment: Yes, that works for the degree symbol. I'm still interested in the answer for any expression...

Comment: @Ben "any" expression? You're not going to be able to represent things like "sqrt(x)" in character strings because of the way the square-root operator is drawn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your keyboard does not provide the degree symbol `°` the character can be obtained with its [UTF8 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), which in this case is 176:

```
paste0(angles,intToUtf8(176))
#[1] "10.2°" "20.3°" "14.3°" "18.4°"
```

By using the UTF8 code any character can be pasted like this. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this an answer for "any expression"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to use the labels on a plot, code like this would work

```
angles <- c(10.2, 20.3, 14.3, 18.4)
labels <-sapply(angles, function(a)bquote(.(a) * degree))

plot(1:4, 1:4)
mapply(text, labels = labels, x = 1:4, y = 1:4, pos = 4:1)
```